# Container height inside of Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is my code.

```
Card(
      child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Icon(Icons.home)
              ,),
            Column(
              children: [
                Text('aliazad'),
                Text('aliazad'),
                Text('aliazad'),
                Text('aliazad'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

I want to make the height of the container equal to the height of the card.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your `Row` with a `Container` and give it a `height` like this:

```
Card(
        child: Container(
          height: 80,
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Icon(Icons.home),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text('aliazad'),
                  Text('aliazad'),
                  Text('aliazad'),
                  Text('aliazad'),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: But size of my card should be dynamic.

Comment: Use `Wrap` in place of `Row` instead